# Chaining HTTP requests in Electron using request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, chaining

## UPDATE

OK so I worked it out. When using highland.js I needed a .done() to finish the stream.

```
var requests = [];           
_(fs.createReadStream("small.txt", { encoding: 'utf8' }))
        .splitBy('-----BEGIN-----\n')
        .splitBy('\n-----END-----\n')
        .filter(chunk => chunk !== '')
        .each(function (x) {

            requests.push(function (next) {
                Helpers.Authenticate()
                    .then(function (response1) {
                        return Helpers.Retrieve();
                    })
                    .then(function (response2) {
                        return Helpers.Retrieve();
                    })
                    .then(function () {
                        next();
                    });
            });

        })}).done(function () {
        async.waterfall(requests);
    });
```

The `request` array is now working.

---

I'm having some issues using electron and chained promises. Heres my code that being run in the main process.

```
var request = require('request-promise');
request.post(tppAuthenticate)
    .then(function (responseFromFirstPost) {
        var newoptions = tppRetrieveCertificate(responseFromFirstPost.APIKey)
        return request.post(newoptions) // The return is important
    })
    .then(function (responseFromSecondPost) {
        console.log(responseFromSecondPost)
    })
```

The entire code block executes several thousand times as its called by iterating over each line of a file. The first request gets fired continuously, but this seems to significantly block/throttle back the second request which is only getting called periodically.

I was hoping that the entire block would get called in sequence but this does not seem to be happening.

Heres my complete code block including the iteration:

```
        const _ = require('highland');
        const request = require('request-promise');

        fs.createReadStream(files[0], { encoding: 'utf8' }))
         .splitBy('-----BEGIN -----\n')
         .splitBy('\n-----END -----\n')
         .filter(chunk => chunk !== '')

         // .each(_.log);
         .each(function (x) {

             request.post(tppHelpers.Authenticate)
                 .then(function (responseFromFirstPost) {
                     const newoptions = tppHelpers.tppRetrieveCertificate(responseFromFirstPost.APIKey)
                     console.log(newoptions)
                     return request.post(newoptions) // The return is important
                 })
                 .then(function (responseFromSecondPost) {
                     console.log(responseFromSecondPost)
                     event.sender.send('selected-directory', responseFromSecondPost)
                 })

         });
```

Comment: Could you clarify: do you want the requests of line 2 to start after both requests for line 1 have finished? The way I understand your description, you seem to create several thousand requests synchronously in parallel which will definitely affect the secondary requests.

Comment: @kraf that's how I read it as well: a whole lot of requests get started, probably either overwhelming the event queue or the network, which means the secondary requests will get severely delayed.

Comment: Basically the first and second responses are linked and need to be executed immediately in series otherwise the API key times out. The second requests are executing but very slowly, they are blocked by the first requests. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Are you saying I actually have 3 requests here ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what's happen. If I use python everything works fine, but that's a different thing

Comment: @user1513388 you are saying "the entire code block executes several thousand times". If you do that incorrectly, you're starting several thousand concurrent HTTP requests. Can you show how you implemented the iteration?

Comment: It looks as if you have a call to `request.post(tppAuthenticate)` for every line which will happen concurrently in Javascript automatically. Python waits for both requests to finish before processing the next line. This is not entirely trivial, but described really well in this promise tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ -> chapter "Creating a sequence".

Comment: @user1513388 Did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633709/chaining-http-requests-in-electron-using-request-promise/39634522#39634522) work for you?

Comment: @rsp No still struggling here. I now have it working with `async` but seem to be hitting the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to fire every request at once, which seems to be the case reading the comments you made, then instead of running everything in parallel with:

```
.each(function (x) {
  // ...
});
```

You can instead create an empty array before you run `fs.createReadStream`:

```
var requests = [];
```

and in your `each` callback create functions to add to your array:

```
.each(function (x) {
  requests.push(function (next) {
    // ...
    next();
  });
});
```

and then you can run it in series with:

```
async.series(requests);
```

using the [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module.

Just make sure that the `next()` is called at the right moment, e.g. in the last `.then()` callback of the given chain of promises.

Another way would be to use `async.queue`:

```
var queue = async.queue(function(x, callback) {
  // 
  callback();
}, 1);
```

(Here make sure that the `callback()` is called when it should. Instead of 1 at the end you could use some other number to have a certain number of requests done in parallel.)

And then in your `each` callback:

```
.each(function (x) {
  queue.push(x);
});
```

See the [async.queue](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.queue) docs for more info. (Thanks to robertklep for mentioning `async.queue()` in the comments.)

By the way: do you even use the `x` in your iterations or are you just making a bunch of identical request for each line of your input?

### Example

To answer your question from the comments, here is a way to construct the array of functions.

If this was your original code:

```
yourStream.each(function (x) {
  doRequest1()
  .then(function (response1) {
    return doRequest2();
  })
  .then(function (response2) {
    return doRequest3();
  });
});
```

Then you could consruct that array of functions with something like:

```
var requests = [];
yourStream.each(function (x) {
  requests.push(function (next) {
    doRequest1()
    .then(function (response1) {
      return doRequest2();
    })
    .then(function (response2) {
      return doRequest3();
    })
    .then(function () {   
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

And you could run them with:

```
async.series(requests);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: [`async.queue()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.queue) is also really useful for these sorts of things.

Comment: @rsp Thanks for this. I'm still struggling a bit here. This async stuff is real a pain and there's so many different ways to do it. The x will be used because thats what I need to feed into my HTTP requests.

Comment: @rsp You mention "create functions to add to your array" what would these functions look like ?

Comment: @rsp - thanks very much. Problem here is that `request` is not accessible outside of the .each function.